# How to fix cc1plus.exe: out of memory allocating 65536 bytes

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile a c++ program (that is 22MB). However I can't compile it because my compiler(MinGW) says:

```
cc1plus.exe: out of memory allocating 65536 bytes
```

I have searched much about it and I pretty much know what it is, but I have no idea how to fix it.
And if you are wondering why is the file so fricking big, that's because i have hard coded images in there.

If you have any ideas how to fix this, please tell me :)

Comment: have you tried `--stack,32000000`?

Comment: What do you mean by *c++ program (that is 22MB)*? You can't compile it, so it's not a program yet. Is this the size of source code file? Is this the size of an array that you try to allocate in your program?

Comment: Sorry, I mean that the c++ source file is 22MB large.

Comment: Why is it 22MB? Imbedded data? Split the source file into smaller parts if possible.

Comment: If you have image*s*, plural, start with separating them into their own files.

Comment: It would certainly make sense to separate your embedded data and code into separate files so that you don't have to recompile your data every time you change the code

Comment: Separating the images to another files would make it work, but the whole point of the code is that the images are in the executable file.

Comment: The images can still be part of the executable if they are in other source files.  How did you convert the images into C++ code?

Comment: I just read the image files with ifstream and saved the image as an integer array.

Comment: That is fine. Save them into more than 1 cpp file. Perhaps a different cpp file per image.

Comment: I put the whole array to header file and included it and it actually worked :) But I noticed that putting it to another cpp file did not work.  And thank you all for helping!

Answer (score 0):

Putting the hard coded images to another header file and including it to the the original cpp file solves the issue.